# Ionic 3 youtube player plugin not open youtube video in portrait mode

Tags: ionic3

I am using ionic youtube player plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/youtube-video-player/ to play youtube video in my app. Problem is it only open youtube videos in landscape mode not in portrait mode, following is the code where i use this plugin.

```
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  app = 'youtube://';
} else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  app = 'com.google.android.youtube';
}

this.appAvailability.check(app)
  .then(
    (yes: boolean) => {
      this.youtube.openVideo(azkar.video_id.split('?v=')[1]); //using plugin method here
    },
    (no: boolean) => {
      console.log(zikrName.length);

      if(azkar.video_id == null){
        console.log(azkar.video_id);
        this.toastProvider.getToastAlert('Video for this zikr not available');
      }
      else{
        let iab = this.inAppBrowser.create(azkar.video_id);
        iab.show();
        }
    },
  );
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?